# Adding button with click event on popupTemplate in ArcGIS JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I meet a problem when trying to add button on popupTemplate in ArcGIS JavaScript;My environment is node.js, and the version of ArcGIS JavaScript is 4.28.
The code snippet is as following:

```
const popupTemplate = {
    title: "{Name}",
    content: "{Description}"
}

var graphicID = "testing_1";
const buttonHTML = `<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteSelectedDiagram('${graphicID}')">Delete the Diagram</button>`;

graphic = new Graphic({
    geometry: new geometry.Polygon({
        rings: coordinates,
        spatialReference: {
            wkid: 3826
        },
        id:"testing_1"
    }),
    symbol: {
        type: "simple-fill",
        color: [255, 0, 0, 0.3], // Red color with 0.3 opacity
        outline: {
            color: [255, 0, 0], // Red color
            width: 1
        }
    },
    attributes: {
        Name: "Diagram Infos",
        Description: buttonHTML
    },
    popupTemplate: popupTemplate
});
```

However, it is not working,the css style of button is disappear and popupTemplate only show the words "Delete the Diagram".

Is there any method to add button with click event to popupTemplate?